# Integral involving a difference and an even function

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, substitution

This seems very basic, however, it's been bugging me all weekend.  A TA for one of my engineering courses wrote this on the board the other day:

$$\int_{-a}^{a} \mathrm{d}x_1\int_{-a}^{a} \mathrm{d}x_2\operatorname{sinc}(x_1-x_2)=2a\int_{-2a}^{2a}\mathrm{d}x\left(1-\frac{|x|}{2a}\right)\operatorname{sinc}(x),$$

where $\operatorname{sinc}(x)=\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$.

This is very nice as it reduces the number of integrals. I also recall that he mentioned that this works for any even function, not just $\operatorname{sinc}$.

I am stumped as to how one derives this.  I am familiar with variable substitution, but I can't figure out how one removes one of the integrals.  Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's think of what we are integrating, so that you can get an intuitive idea of how this works. We are integrating with respect to two variables around a square of side length $2a$. We are only interested in the positive difference between the two variables, since we have an even function. So what we can do is take a weighted average of all the differences between the two variables in the square, and then use that to integrate across all the x values.

The weight for each x value will be proportional to the length of that diagonal on the square which represents $x-y=c$, where c is some constant between $-2a$ and $2a$. Thus the weight will be $2a-|x|$, and so we have our equality:
For an even function $f(x)$, we have
$$\int_{-a}^{a}\int_{-a}^{a}f(x_1-x_2)dx_1dx_2=\int_{-2a}^{2a}(2a-|x|)f(x)dx$$